# How to get the blob data from Oracle in C#4.0?

Tags: c#-4.0

Here i have a requriment to read the data from Oracle DB.In that one column is defined as BLOB.using that data i need to frame the insert query like this "insert into emp values('100','John',EMP_PIC);
Here emp_pic is defined as BLOB.Please suggest me some idea's about this.I am using C#4.0.

Comment: What *are* you asking? How to read or how to write the blob? Have you tried something? Have you tried passing the values as paremeters?

Comment: Also, which provider are you using? Oracle's? Microsoft's? A third party like Devart?

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you can use this sample project based on this link. I hope this help.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13365/Insert-retrieve-an-image-into-from-a-blob-field-in

if you wanna get value from blob data using OracleDataReader just convert first byte to image using this:

```
private Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
            ms.Position = 0;
            Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
            return returnImage;
        }
```

then read data blob like this:

```
picFileData.Image = byteArrayToImage(dr["EMP_PIC"] as byte[]); // dr is OracleDataReader dr;
```

picFileData is PictureBox from visual studio and EMP_PIC is blob column in Oracle

Comment: How is this answer relevant to the question? The code doesn't show how to insert or read the data in the first place

Comment: this answer is really relevant, i used it in my project and worked

Comment: Used *what* in your project? There is no ADO.NET code in this answer. Besides, the OP asks how to *insert* a BLOB, not read it. Answers that just point to a link with no explanation aren't considered high quality

Comment: i have attach link above, and it will give solution how to insert data to blob data oracle

Comment: As I said, link-only answers are considered low quality. Where in this entire article is the answer? If you don't want to explain and provide the relevant snippet, this should be a comment, not an answer. In fact, that article *doesn't* actually show how to read a single BLOB. It does show how to store it

Comment: *Ugh* that article mixes dynamic sql with parameters! What's the point of using concatenation to pass simple values *and* parameters to pass the BLOB in the same sentence? Why not use parameters for all? This code should *never* appear in production!

Answer (score -1):

Try to use LINQ to SQL. This is very useful.

Comment: How it could be helpful for me ?

Comment: you will skip a lot of "hard" operation

Comment: @Arbejdsglæde what "hard" operation? The OP asks how to read a blob, not how to avoid writing SQL statements. A blob is equivalent to `varbinary(max)/image` and usually *shouldn't* be read with a simple SELECT. Perhaps this should be a comment instead of an answer?